# How to call template within plugin folder?

Tags: wordpress

I want to call/load template file inside plugin folder.

Any suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your template directory is inside your main plugin directory:

```
$plugindir = plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ );
load_template( $plugindir . 'templates/some-template.php' );
```

See:

[load_template()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_template/)

[plugin_dir_path()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/)